Failed to parse ELF file during 'solana program deploy'
Error: ELF error: ELF error: Failed to parse ELF file: Section or symbol name `.data._ZN12wasm_` is longer than `16` bytes


I wonder if the program was built incorrectly. The section name of .data._ZN12wasm_ might be coincidence, but since it has "wasm" in the name, it makes me think this is not a Solana BPF program, but rather a WASM program. Be sure to give more information about your project and how it was built so we can help!
